# Add header and footer to list view without setting adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple list view, and I want to add header and footer to this list view without setting an adapter for it.

How do I add a header and footer to a `ListView` without setting an adapter, if it is possible?

xml code for listView:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

and code for adding header and footer:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);        

Button headerButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
headerButton.setText("Header");
listView.addHeaderView(headerButton);

Button footerButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
footerButton.setText("Footer");
listView.addFooterView(footerButton);
```

Comment: Can't really use a ListView properly without an adapter, nor can you add these header/footer views

Comment: If you cant have a header and a footer without an adapter. Your best bet is to add an adapter without any data.  That could possible work.

Comment: tnx i did that before asking but it would be better if there be a way to add header and footer to a listview without setting an adapter for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve that.

The way header and footer layouts work with ListView is the following: Whenever you add a header or footer to your ListView, it will cause your own adapter to be wrapped by a [WrapperListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/WrapperListAdapter.html) and basically make your header and footer items be treated as list items in their own way(handled by the adapter of course). Thus, your ListView can't really know about these items if it has no adapter.